# ST_EXTENT or ST_ENVELOPE in BigQuery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, gis, user-defined-functions

I want the equivalent of `ST_EXTENT` or `ST_ENVELOPE` in BigQuery, but I can't find a way to make this query run:

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_EXTRACT(name, ', (..)') state
  , ST_EXTENT(ARRAY_AGG(urban_area_geom)) corners
  , COUNT(*) cities
FROM `bigquery-public-data.geo_us_boundaries.urban_areas`
GROUP BY state
```

The desired result of this query is a list of bounding boxes to cover all urban areas around the US, grouped by state.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I created a feature request to get a native implementation of ST_EXTENT(). Please add your votes and evidence of why you need this function so the team can prioritize and keep you informed of any developments:

- https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/148915449

In the meantime, the best solution I can offer:

- `fhoffa.x.st_bounding_box()`: a naive bounding box UDF.

Use it like this:

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_EXTRACT(name, ', (..)') state
  , fhoffa.x.st_bounding_box(ARRAY_AGG(urban_area_geom)).polygon 
  , COUNT(*) urban_areas
FROM `bigquery-public-data.geo_us_boundaries.urban_areas`
GROUP BY state
```

[image]

[image]
The code behind it:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fhoffa.x.st_bounding_box(arr ANY TYPE) AS ((
  SELECT AS STRUCT *
    , ST_MakePolygon(ST_GeogFromText(FORMAT('LINESTRING(%f %f,%f %f,%f %f,%f %f)',minlon,minlat,maxlon,minlat,maxlon,maxlat,minlon, maxlat))) polygon
  FROM (
    SELECT MIN(m.min_x) minlon, MAX(m.max_x) maxlon , MIN(m.min_y) minlat, MAX(m.max_y) maxlat
    FROM (
      SELECT 
        (SELECT AS STRUCT MIN(x) min_x, MAX(x) max_x, MIN(y) min_y, MAX(y) max_y FROM UNNEST(coords)) m
      FROM (
        SELECT ARRAY(
          SELECT STRUCT(
            CAST(SPLIT(c, ', ')[OFFSET(0)] AS FLOAT64) AS x, 
            CAST(SPLIT(c, ', ')[OFFSET(1)] AS FLOAT64) AS y
          )
          FROM UNNEST(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(ST_ASGEOJSON(geog), r'\[([^[\]]*)\]')) c
        ) coords
        FROM UNNEST(arr) geog
      )
    )
  )
))
```

Notes:

- Additional effort is needed to make it work with geometries that cross the -180 line.
- Due to geodesic edges, the function result is not a true bounding box, i.e. ST_Covers(box, geom) might return FALSE.
- In the picture above I'm not expecting each state to be fully covered, just its urban areas. So the bounding box is correct if there's no urban area in those uncovered corners.
- The following polygon construction will give you exact "rectangles", but they become much more complex structures to work with.

```sql
ST_GEOGFROMGEOJSON(
  FORMAT('{"type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [[[%f,%f],[%f,%f],[%f,%f],[%f,%f],[%f, %f]]]}'
  , minlon,minlat,maxlon,minlat,maxlon,maxlat,minlon,maxlat,minlon,minlat)
)
```

[image]

I'll be looking forward to your comments and suggestions.

Answer (score 4):

Since September 27, 2021 BigQuery support [ST_BOUNDINGBOX](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/geography_functions#st_boundingbox) and [ST_EXTENT](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/geography_functions#st_extent)

Answer (score 1):

ST_ENVELOPE doesn't exist yet, but can be emulated by transforming the STRUCT result from ST_BOUNDINGBOX back to a geography:

```sql
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION ST_Envelope(polygon geography) RETURNS geography AS (( SELECT ST_GeogFromText(FORMAT('POLYGON((%f %f,%f %f,%f %f,%f %f, %f %f))', b.xmin, b.ymin, b.xmax, b.ymin, b.xmax, b.ymax, b.xmin, b.ymax, b.xmin, b.ymin)) FROM (SELECT ST_BOUNDINGBOX(polygon) AS b) ));
```

Comment: Note that the edges of the geographies follow geodesic lines, while the bounding box is computed in lon-lat "flat" space. With large shapes, the "Envelope" computed this way (1) does not always cover its argument geography fully, (2) might be wider than needed. This might be OK for small shapes, but be careful. See https://medium.com/geospatial-analytics/squaring-the-sphere-974d1e4a875e for long explanation.

Comment: Also, a shorter version to avoid repeated ST_BoundingBox:
```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION ST_Envelope(polygon geography) RETURNS geography
AS ((
  SELECT ST_GeogFromText(FORMAT('POLYGON((%f %f,%f %f,%f %f,%f %f, %f %f))',
  b.xmin, b.ymin, b.xmax, b.ymin, b.xmax, b.ymax, b.xmin, b.ymax, b.xmin, b.ymin)) 
  FROM (SELECT ST_BOUNDINGBOX(polygon) AS b)
));
```

Comment: Thanks, I updated my comment. I agree this is not optimal, but it seems to be the "simplest" way to get a good approximation, even if it does break down at larger scale.